# When to reject the null hypothesis given a uniformly most powerful test?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a random variable that takes values in $\{-1,0,1\}$. We want to test

$H_{0}:Pr(X = -1|\Theta = 0) = Pr(X = 0|\Theta = 0) = Pr(X = 1| \Theta = 0) = 1/3$

versus

$H_{1}=Pr(X = -1 |\Theta = 1) = Pr(X = 1|\Theta = 1) = 1/4,\,Pr(X = 0|\Theta = 1) = 1/2.$

**Exercise:** Calculate the power of this test and show that the UMP test of size $\alpha=1/3$ based on $X$ leads to rejecting the null hypothesis when $X=0$.

**My attempt:** I'm new to this subject and am not sure what a general approach is to these types of questions so any help regarding that would also be much appreciated. Anyway, I figured it would be good to use the Neyman-Pearson Lemma about uniformly most powerful tests but that was about as far as I got.

Thanks!

Comment: You wrote "Calculate the power of this test" but there is no test provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate likelihood ratio $\frac{L_0(X)}{L_1(X)}$ for $X=-1,0,1$ separately: 
$$
\dfrac{L_0(-1)}{L_1(-1)}=\dfrac{L_0(1)}{L_1(1)}=\dfrac{1/3}{1/4}=\frac43,
$$
$$
\dfrac{L_0(0)}{L_1(0)}=\dfrac{1/3}{1/2}=\frac23.
$$
Likelihood ratio for $X=0$ is smaller than for $X=\pm 1$. UMP test rejects null hypothesis for small values of likelihood ratio, so we can simply try to find size  of a test 
$$
\delta(X) = \begin{cases}H_0, & \frac{L_0(X)}{L_1(X)} >\frac23,\cr H_1, & \frac{L_0(X)}{L_1(X)} \leq \frac23 \end{cases} = \begin{cases}H_0, & X = \pm 1,\cr H_1, & X=0\end{cases} 
$$
If it is equal to $\frac13$, we construct the UMP test of size $\alpha=\frac13$.
$$\alpha=\mathbb P_{H_0}(\delta=H_1)=\mathbb P_{H_0}(X=0)=\frac13$$ as required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did write ''give the power of this test'' in the wrong place, apologies. It is asked to compute the power of the UMP test of size $\alpha=1/3$. I'm not quite getting a step in your answer though so maybe you could help me out. You give the size of the test and then say ''if it is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$, we can construct the UMP test of size $\alpha=1/3$. I'm not getting what you mean by this and how the earlier representation of $\delta(X)$ represents the size of the test. Could you elaborate? I'm new to the subject so maybe I'm missing easy terms.

Comment: @S.Crim I mean that if the size of the decribed test is $1/3$, this is exactly the test we needed: it is UMP since it is constructed by NP Lemma, and it has required size.

Comment: What would the power of the test you just gave be in this case?

Comment: Do you know the definition of test power? The answer follows immediately from the definition.

Comment: I am familiar with the definition. The power of a test is the probability of correctly rejecting the null-hypothesis when the alternative is true. However, I don't see how this follows directly from your solution. I'm probably missing something stupid.

Comment: The test $\delta(X)$ is given. Simply find $\beta=\mathbb P_{H_1}(\delta=H_1)$.